# Web scraping in Python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to web scraping and i am facing a problem. In the appending part, it seems to append only the first row of the table I want to scrape! I am sure I am missing something. Any ideas? Thanks in advance! The code snippet is the following:

```
driver = visit_main_page()

contents = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]')

tables = contents[0].find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table')

data = {"Date": [], "Time": [], "Place": [], "Latitude": [], "Longitude": [], "Fatalities": [], "Magnitude": []}

for i in tables:

    try:
        dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')
        times = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]')
        places = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]')
        lat = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]')
        long = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]')
        fat = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]')
        magn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[7]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('No such content!')
        pass
    time.sleep(1)

    for d in dates:
        data['Date'].append(d.text)

    for t in times:
        data['Time'].append(t.text)

    for p in places:
        data['Place'].append(p.text)

    for la in lat:
        data['Latitude'].append(la.text)

    for lo in long:
        data['Longitude'].append(lo.text)

    for f in fat:
        data['Fatalities'].append(f.text)

    for m in magn:
        data['Magnitude'].append(m.text)
```

Comment: can you share the link to that page?

Comment: If there is a table on the page that you want try using pandas: `pandas.read_html(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**
You are using a wrong locators.
All the parameters you are trying to grab are starting with `//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table[2]` - this points to a specific table.
To collect the data you are looking for try this:

```
dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'wikitable')]//tbody//tr//td[1]")
times = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'wikitable')]//tbody//tr//td[2]")
places = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'wikitable')]//tbody//tr//td[3]")
lat = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'wikitable')]//tbody//tr//td[4]")
long = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'wikitable')]//tbody//tr//td[5]")
fat = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'wikitable')]//tbody//tr//td[6]")
magn = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'wikitable')]//tbody//tr//td[7]")


dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'wikitable')]//tbody//tr//td[1]")
```

This is the main problem. The code after that looks correct.
You have no to get `contents` and `tables` with this approach

Comment: Unfortunately replacing with the i didn't work. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Have you update the XPath also as I mentioned and wrote here?

Comment: Yeah...I'll have a look again in case i missed something!

Comment: The `.` at the beginning of XPath locator like `'.//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]'`

Comment: Yeah..i changed that as well! Still no luck

Comment: Is it possible to see that web page? I asked you for that from the very beginning...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_earthquakes_2001%E2%80%932010

Comment: @MariannaKaravangeli Did this resolve your problem?

Comment: Yeah yeah...I chose to go with the read_html() pandas method though!